# Move or save an image inserted into a Google Sheets cell to Drive

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

We use google sheets on smartphones for entering trucking load data.  We insert 8 to 10 images for each truckload into a Sheets cell and it works perfectly.  But, at the end of the day, we can have nearly 1000 images depending on how many trucks we've loaded.  I need a way to rename and send each pic to a specific Google Drive folder so they're indexed and accessible as individual image (jpg) files.

We've uploaded pics to Drive first, manually renamed/indexed them and then inserted the links into the sheets with the specific truckload.  It's extremely time-consuming, need to automate through code.

Comment: Need more details.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: That's the problem, I haven't tried any code because I haven't figured out how to extract the image from the cell as a .jpg file.  Using the plus sign '+' in Google Sheets mobile, we choose to insert image into cell or over cell (the new feature that was added back in March '19).  So, I'm asking how do I extract that image as a .jpg file that can then be directed to a folder in drive.